# Visual Basic Trimming Letters From Integer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to trim letters of a string? Or Convert a string to an integer removing its letters from it?

Story:
I have in which I have bunch of options on an application and all of them add up points depending on the option selected by the user. I gave them values like hsq2 hsq4 hsq6 and now I need to be able to get the one that is selected and remove letters from it and add up values. If you know a better way of doing this please let me know also..

[image]

Comment: store the logic value for each RB in the Tag property.  or use a class and put the app logic there instead of the UI

Comment: can you give me an example code to give me an idea?

Comment: parsing control text for a critical value is a bad idea and fragile.  in the IDE set the tag property to the value you want to use. e.g. High School Quality "4" give it a value of 8; then use that in code.  A simple class of Name/Value to store what to show and value to use would work even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way would be to use `XAML` and databinding to a rich ViewModel that has separate properties for each item's label and its score value as an integer. Then a method on your ViewModel would perform the sum of selected values and return it for data binding to the Total Score display. Search for MVVM if you want to know more about that approach.

However, since it looks like you're building a WinForms app, you could use the Tag property of each element to store the integer value. That's how I would have done it 7 years ago.

Comment: Tag is the king! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There are better designs you could use to avoid the issue, but to extract the number from a string, you could use a regex (now you have two problems, as they say!).

```
Dim match = RegEx.Match("blah2", "\d+")
If match.Success Then
    Dim val = CInt(match.Value)
    ' val = 2
End If
```